# Is it bad to allow my client to query my backend?

Tags: swift, database, xcode

I am coding an application which utilizes `parse-server` (hosted by heroku). The application is quite complex, with database queries for objects, maps, users, messaging, comments, etc... A large amount of the information pulled is handled by functions that live in the client such as the following:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Example")
query.whereKey("Name", equalTo: "Value")
query.findObjectsInBacgkround(block: { (objects, error) in
   //do stuff
})
```

This is very general, but this structure is used all over the application (living in the client) to call for objects from the database. My question is fairly simple: Is this a bad idea? Is it a bad idea to have the client querying the server? I ask because somebody made a comment suggesting that this should be avoided because someone could essentially decompile my application, and then make calls to the server for any pieces of information they wanted, after modifying the query. There is an ACL in place for all objects such that sensitive info would be prevented from being pulled in this way, in theory. I certainly can understand the issue with this, but I am curious as to why I haven't seen that sort of sentiment ever echoed in questions on stack or on the internet about this kind of client to server querying?

Comment: No. You should make a server-side application that only exposes safe operations to a public API.

Comment: @Alexander no its not a bad idea? Or no, I shouldn't do it this way?

Comment: No, you shouldn't do it. You should make a proper server side app, instead.

Comment: @Alexander can you explain why that is? Is it because of what I mentioned?

Comment: Because anybody could just read all of your data, including customer names, addresses, emails, etc.

Comment: Unless this is an internal application, and your users are knowledgeable, do NOT do that.  Anyone with knowledge of SQL (I assume it's a relational database) could view, modify, hack, destroy, ... your data and-or database.  Only DBAs should have direct access to the database.  A secured application, which validates user inputs and imposes access restrictions should be exposed to clients.

Comment: You need to look up three tier programming, your client code should never directly access your database. This question is echoed all over stack overflow, It usually just lies under the SQL or database tags. It leaves you open to all kinds of attacks. It has to do with prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. It violates multiple computer programming rules, namely the principal of least privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody decompiling your code to query your database shouldn't be one of your worries, but that said, what you're trying to do is not the way to go. What you should do is handle these queries on the server, and expose this to the user through an API that you'd build. When the user makes a request, you can validate on the server if they're allowed to make that request, and if they are you can send back the data from the query!

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive response. Can you explain a little further what that would look like? Where would I set up the functions for the server to query this information? How would I (in the client) write to the server to perform the query, and how do I handle the returning of the data? Are these functions written in my `index.js` folder of my server? How do I call them on the client?

Comment: Hey @AlekPiasecki, how to make a backend is really too much for me to go into here. You can use a web framework of your liking, I use Laravel. It has great documentation and allows me to easily make an API. It's a rabbit hole you'd have to dive in but definitely worth learning!

Comment: ok I understand that this may be very complicated. Can you at least explain the difference between what I currently have set up (Parse-server hosted by heroku) vs a 'web framework'. Are these not the same things? Do I not already have one set up, I just need to modify the way it interacts with the client?

Comment: heroku is a Platform as a service, a web framework is a programming environment that is used to accomplish, client, server, database interaction. If you are familiar with javascript you might want to consider learning the node.js environment and consider using express coupled with mongodb for database, or the MEAN stack